# Show value of activity.trackable with public_activity Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the public_activity gem to track changes with my Reposts model, which contains a comment_id and belongs_to the Comments table. In the **_create.html.erb** partial for the create action of a Repost, I can use this code with no errors:

```
<%= activity.trackable.comment %>
```

and the view will display this text:

```
Comment:0x00000004508ee0>
```

Which proves that it's displaying the Activerecord using the relationship I established between Reposts and Comments. However, once I try to extend the code to show the content field on the Comments table I get an error. For example:

```
<%= activity.trackable.comment.content %>
```

Returns the following error:

```
undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass
```

activity.trackable.comment seems to pull the right record. How can I extend this so not only does it pull the record via the established relationship, but that it also pulls another field from that table?

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Full view for **views/public_activity/_create.html.erb**

```
<% if activity.trackable %>
  <%= link_to activity.trackable.comment, activity.trackable.comment %>
  <% else %>
  which has since been removed
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 2: Per Leo's assistance, all I had to do was check for nil. Here's what I had to change my code to:**

```
<% if activity.trackable && activity.trackable.comment.present? %>
 <%= link_to activity.trackable.comment.content, activity.trackable.comment %>
  <% else %>
  which has since been removed
<% end %>
```

I highly recommend adding that additional code to check for **nil** if you followed along the public_activity Railscast like I did.

Comment: Are you iterating through a list of activities? Is there any chance that `trackable.comment` is returning a nil object?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Leo. I posted the entire partial view code. This does affect all of the activities listed on the page but the field is filled out for all of the rows in the database so far. Blank fields shouldn't be causing the issue

Comment: Where is the `activity` variable getting set? To me it seems like it should work fine, fetching the relationship object `comment` should allow you to get its fields by default unless you specify it not to...what is happening is that activity.trackable.comment is returning a nil object. So `comment` is not a AR object. That's why I asked if you're iterating through activities or what not.

Comment: So reading up on the public_activity gem and looking at the Railscast. It seems to me that you're pretty much trying to do the same thing as in the Railscasts. Are you running into issues form that? If not I'd suggest looking at it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast

Comment: I actually used the Railscast to setup my app. I'm even using the same code activity.trackable.content for another model and it doesn't error at all. I'm not sure what could be different. Could it be an issue with how I setup my Repost and Comments relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure...You could post your Comments model and maybe we'd be able to help :)

Comment: Leo, that was it! I can't believe all I had to do was check for nil. Post an answer and I'll mark it as the correct solution for you! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'd do the check one of the two ways `!activity.trackable.comment.nil?` or a railsy way `activity.trackable.comment.present?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems per this particular question, the `activity.trackable.comment` was returning a `NilClass` object for some activities causing the exception to be thrown.

The fix of course is to check to make sure `comment` is not nil by doing the following

```
<% if activity.trackable && activity.trackable.comment.present? %>
 <%= link_to activity.trackable.comment.content, activity.trackable.comment %>
  <% else %>
  which has since been removed
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're accessing the wrong object to get a count from. I've used the `impressionist_count` method for this sort of task in the past, the documentation [here](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) might help you.

Comment: Doesn't seem he's getting a count..He's trying to the a Comment's content. Just seems the Comment Object returned by public_activity is nil in his case.